# gulp / rollup / typescript — __decorate is not defined

Tags: typescript, gulp, rollupjs, typescript-decorator

I have this `gulpfile.js`

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import { rollup } from 'rollup';
import rollupTypescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

const compileTs = async (src, dest) => {
  const bundle = await rollup({
    input: src,
    plugins: [
      rollupTypescript()
    ]
  });

  await bundle.write({
    file: dest,
    format: 'es',
    name: 'library',
    sourcemap: 'inline'
  });
}

export const ts = async _ => await Promise.all([
    compileTs('./src/ts/main.ts', './bin/js/bin.js')
  ]);
```

within `tsconfig.json` (same directory) I have:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "target": "ESNEXT",
  "module": "ESNext",
  "importHelpers": true, 
  "experimentalDecorators": true
}
```

within `src/ts/main.ts` there is:

```
const Foo = (fx: Function) => {
  console.log(fx);
}

@Foo
class Bar {

}
```

`$ npx gulp ts` creates the desired file. But when I run it the console tells me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __decorate is not defined
```

Since all the helpers from `tslib` are not included.

What can I do to fix that? I have tried to use `external: ['tslib']`, but no luck.

*BTW:* Just running `npx tsc` (plus the outdir set) includes `__decorate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run exactly the same situation before. The issue is likely the option `importHelper` is excluded https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript#ignored-options.

I did resolve by switching to use `rollup-plugin-typescript2` which enables this option by default.

```js
// Install `npm i -D rollup-plugin-typescript2`
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
```

Comment: Thanks for that direction! Just out of interest:  in the docs of `@rollup/plugin-typescript` it is said that: »the tslib helper module always must be used.« - does that mean that it is possible to include `tslib` somehow?

Comment: I had tried but no luck :) that's why I changed to the forked one

Comment: Thanks! I will give `v2` it a shot !